# "< <(command-here)" shell idiom resulting in "redirection unexpected"

Tags: bash, shell, redirect, stdin

This command works fine:

```
$ bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

However, I don't understand how exactly `stable` is passed as a parameter to the shell script that is downloaded by curl. That's the reason why I fail to achieve the same functionality from within my own shell script - it gives me `./foo.sh: 2: Syntax error: redirection unexpected`:

```
$ cat foo.sh 
#!/bin/sh
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

So, the questions are: how exactly this `stable` param gets to the script, why are there two redirects in this command, and how do I change this command to make it work inside my script?

Comment: ...by the way, using file extensions for scripts is considered bad form -- if someone starting `yourcommand` has to call `yourcommand.sh`, what do you do when it's rewritten in Perl or Python? Make all the callers change their scripts, or have a misleading name? Neither is much fun.

Comment: I think you actually have multiple questions here -- one is wondering why the `< <()` thing is happening, another is the use of `bash -s` and the handling the command-line arguments. These should probably be asked as separate questions rather than conflated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Regarding the "redirection unexpected" error:

That's not related to `stable`, it's related to your script using `/bin/sh`, not `bash`. The `<()` syntax is unavailable in POSIX shells, which includes bash when invoked as `/bin/sh` (in which case it turns off nonstandard functionality for compatibility reasons).

Make your shebang line `#!/bin/bash`.

### Understanding the `< <()` idiom:

To be clear about what's going on -- `<()` is replaced with a filename which refers to the output of the command which it runs; on Linux, this is typically a `/dev/fd/##` type filename. Running `< <(command)`, then, is taking that file and directing it to your stdin... which is pretty close the behavior of a pipe.

To understand why this idiom is useful, compare this:

```
read foo < <(echo "bar")
echo "$foo"
```

to this:

```
echo "bar" | read foo
echo "$foo"
```

The former works, because the read is executed by the same shell that later echoes the result. The latter does not, because the read is run in a subshell that was created just to set up the pipeline and then destroyed, so the variable is no longer present for the subsequent echo.

### Understanding `bash -s stable`:

`bash -s` indicates that the script to run will come in on stdin. All arguments, then, are fed to the script in the `$@` array (`$1`, `$2`, etc), so `stable` becomes `$1` when the script fed in on stdin is run.

Comment: and is there any alternative to `<()` in just `sh`?

Comment: Not to `<()` in the general case, but to the specific case of `< <()`, yes -- instead of `command_one < <(command_two)`, run `command_two | command_one`. They're not quite equivalent in terms of exit status handling and such, and *very* not equivalent if command_one is setting variables or otherwise changing your current shell, but it'll work for your case here.

Comment: the problem is that `stable` is not a command - it is a string literal that is passed to `command_two` as a parameter...

Comment: What does that have to do with anything? It certainly isn't related to the "redirection unexpected" error. `bash -s` simply indicates that commands should be run from stdin, and the `stable`, yes, is an argument which is set to `$1` during that script's execution.

Comment: It's not related to the error, but it's related to the `command_two | command_one` syntax, the script doesn't do `read` - it expects a param

Comment: How does that have anything at all to do with the `command_two | command_one` syntax? `command_one` is, well, your command; if it happens to be `bash -s stable`, then that's what it should be.